# Is there a name for an ordered algebraic structure that models the extended integers (i.e. enhanced with infinity)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, order-theory

Is there a name for an ordered algebraic structure that abstracts the non-negative extended integers (extended in the sense that they include $\infty$), i.e. is there a name for a partially-ordered, abelian monoid with the additional requirement that every $x$, with the possible exception of the maximum, has an inverse? To put it differently, is there a name for a partially-ordered abelian monoid, which, excluding the maximum element (if any), forms a group?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you require the partial order be compatible with the addition? That is, $x \leqslant y$ implies $x+z \leqslant y+z$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Yes.

Comment: How do you define $\infty+(-\infty)$ in your monoid?

Comment: George, I think, is the standard name for them. Named after Prince Regent George IV.

Comment: @Wojowu: Actually, I had in mind a positive partial order (for which $0$ is the minimum). In other words, I am interested in an abstraction of the extended segment $[0,\infty]$ or alternatively $(-\infty,\infty]$, in which case $x+\infty = \infty$. I've now revised my question accordingly.

Comment: I am interested in this topic as well. Namely, an ordered field with "additively absorptive top element". Is there a book on this topic that can be used as a basic reference?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for *partially ordered groups with a top element*. Also known as *po-groups* --c.f. *po-sets*.

These are usually defined as sets having an order and a group operation such that the operation is monotone; i.e., order-preserving.

There are also *po-monoids* and it seems your particular interest is the case of commutative po-monoids with a top element.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not sure this is exactly what I'm looking for, since in a partially ordered group with a top element $t$ it can happen that $t+x < t$ for some element $x$, which is not a desirable behavior, since I need $t+x=t$ for every $x$.

Comment: So you're asking for *po-groups with an additively absorptive top element* ;-)

Comment: This sounds better.

Comment: po-monoids then - a group cannot have an absorptive element